# How to build/cross-compile an existing meson or cmake project under Android AOSP?

Tags: android, cmake, meson-build

I am trying to understand how to build executable and libraries using  Android.mk and Android.bp under AOSP. And I am able to compile simple c programs.

I was wondering if there is a way to cross-compile existing CMake and meson projects under AOSP.

Do I need to manually convert them into Android.mk, Android.bp or does AOSP build system provide any mechanism to directly build meson and CMake projects?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create separate Android.mk or Android.bp. Refer to [mesa3d](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/blob/master/Android.mk) project which uses meson for Linux and has a separate Android.mk to build inside AOSP.

ADD: Also there's another approach to building native projects within AOSP from [glodroid/aospext](https://github.com/GloDroid/aospext), unfortunately not well documented.

Comment: You can also refer to other projects in AOSP/external folder which contains the meson.build file or CMakeLists.txt file for references.